# Android Softkey's next button not taking focus to spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

We have spinner between two text boxes in my Android screen. When the focus is on 1st text box and I am clicking next from softkey, it is directly moving to next textbox instead of the spinner.

Answer (score 2):

Use this way:

```
    firsttextbox.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.edtemail);
    spinner.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.sp1);
    secondtextbox.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.stc);

 firsttextbox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                firsttextbox.clearFocus();
                spinner.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    spinner.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                spinner.clearFocus();
                secondtextbox.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually I am working on framework where A testbox or a spinner cannot know if in the same screen we have other component as spinner.

Comment: @Piyush here you mentioned the ids of the widgets ?