# Open Keyboard for another EditView when click Enter

Tags: android, keyboard, editview

I would like to open the keyboard for another EditView (than the one I am using) when I click Enter on it (when I am in the first EditView).

The scenario should be like this :
I am writing something in the keyboard for the 1st EditView, I have finished so I press "Enter" and it opens the keyboard for the second EditView.

I tried different codes but no success, if somebody could help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found by searching with 'setNextFocusDownld' like Kasper suggested, using this answer : [Android Softkey's next button not taking focus to spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888191/android-softkeys-next-button-not-taking-focus-to-spinner)

The code I used is:

```
mEditText.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.textView2b);
        mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on Enter key press
                    mEditText.clearFocus();
                    mEditText2.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mEditText2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    // Perform action on Enter key press
                    mEditText2.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood here is the answer

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

Comment: What would be the complete code? I tried this which doesnt work:  mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
      KeyEvent event) {
     InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {  mEditText2.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);  return true;

     }
     return false;
    }
   });

Comment: you don't need this. 
Use just mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT); and test

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to switch the focus from 1 EditText to another after pressing Enter.

This can very easily be done by setting the 'setNextFocusDownId' option on your 1st EditText.

firstEditText.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.secondEditTextId);

Comment: Your answer seems interesting but I cannot make it work on my code... Could you give me a sample of code that is working please?

Comment: Sure.  

`EditText firstEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first);`
`EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.second);`
`firstEditText.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.second);`